# How to read this HTTP response (newbie)

Tags: http, decode, response-headers

I have this response and idk how to decode and read it, pls help, im newbie

```
5//qE7rBsoDQmv1hp9cogDD0Q/6Jz1JOGVHUjZhyu6A8d83sovqYjiYNaEugHMbNGuqPD7PEbGiWP0wHaPRtnhcKa5I3vLA0/AVUQlMzOmJuokoHJzxybKleNp7JItVXyI4LxAo9HnlR5H8yZtWHWVVaYU8ajHOIjzUjvLacejejT1+z2zji/G7dtEuGB1EDQcTuYNiQz/S9n/s/P/bgK4F+bMSevztFvz0X2uXKOC81ti9N/s84ReO66x7Wr8SHxx886CfVgW1OWBIoj9s+uH490md68Bg4
```

Comment: First of all, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
This looks like base-64 but seems to be encrypted in a custom format. So no one will be able to help you with this limited information.
I'd suggest you take a look at the page's javascript source to see how it handles the response.

Comment: thx bro , i got string : çÿêºÁ²Ðýa§×(0ôCþÏRNQÔr» <wÍì¢ú&
hK ÆÍê³Älh?Lhôm
k7¼°4üTBS3:bn¢J'<rl©^6É"ÕWÈÄ
=yQä2fÕYUZaOs5#¼¶z7£O_³Û8âünÝ´KQAÄî`ØÏô½û??öà+~lÄ¿;E¿=ÚåÊ8/5¶/MþÏ8EãºëÖ¯ÄÇ<è'ÕmNX(Û>¸~=Ògzð8              . I cant read it

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the 2-minute [tour]. 
Moreover, open [Help] and read at least [ask]. Then, [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].